# How to pass properties of one object to other class?

Tags: java, ide, 2d, greenfoot

I'm currently trying to learn Java and the Greenfoot IDE. I've made a neat lil game, however, I'm struggling with the idea of passing variables from actor objects to world sub classes in order to keep track of the scoring system. 
Would anyone be able to dumb it down for me to super simple terms. I've seen examples using names such as MyClass and ClassA and such but they make no sense to me.

Comment: Have you read the [Greenfoot tutorials](https://www.greenfoot.org/doc)?  Also, you might be more successful asking this sort of question on [Greenfoot's own discussion forums](https://www.greenfoot.org/topics).

Comment: You might a Java tutorial useful: https://www.learnjavaonline.org/
https://www.udemy.com/java-tutorial/  https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-java

Comment: Made question more readable according to the context.